# Magento Store, Storeview and Currency Changer

Tags: multistore, store-switcher

I try to implement a store switcher for switching between `Store`,`Store View` and `Currency`.

With using this line: `Mage::getModel('core/store_group')->getCollection();`

I get the Store names (3 kinds) like: `store 1`,`store 2`

Store 1 has 3 Store views (German, English and Chinese)

How can i generate the link for switching between the Stores? (Not between Store Views)

Comment: Mage::app()->getStore($_websiteId)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK);

Comment: Please add it as an answer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solve:

```
Mage::app()->getStore($_websiteId)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_L‌​INK);
```